# Elixhauser comorbidity index for stata?

Tags: stata

There is known version of the Elixhauser comorbidity index for R, but has it been made available in Stata?

Comment: Have you tried `elixhauser` or `icdpic` from SSC? Usually a goods start to such questions is to type `findit elixhauser` in the command window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are separate files though. All 3 do files neede to make the Elixhauser score.

for [mapping ICD-10 codes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KiktsyQ4dDGNIt4g73lmtHOSEUHygvDz/view?usp=sharing) into the appropriate categories, then [counting categories](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QazL1wID6HdEYLTgnKR5jTPTq-mJPBhM/view?usp=sharing), and [assigning the score](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nHgMuZHIds5Nx3WipUskJ13zURzzpBnB/view?usp=sharing).

As text, the mapp[ing is here the](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1p__qT3Yt1jD1CtWpH8k33E-wjY-o-a02K0JdtdDj7QA/edit?usp=sharing) counting of [category is here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iadgIg8uzjwdqPQiJNbiDosVahXgP_EpAOyIoN8lyU0/edit?usp=sharing), and the [score](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TsYBMp-GT1MU6u2md-vTwsNgo8x3vfw_1dt3oT8A0dM/edit?usp=sharing) is here.